# Docker Desktop -WSL distro terminated abruptly

Tags: docker

When i try to run Node Image in docker that error pop up. Also i try to run any other image an the container runs for serverals seconds and then it stops alone

Update Wsl and reinstall Docker, I also searched several forums and did not find a solution

Comment: Hi @Luca. This looks like a configuration question and not a coding question. As such I think it is likelier to be answered on other stack exchanges. I'd try [superuser](https://superuser.com). Good luck!

Comment: Can you share more detailed information including the error message

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue before. And I also got the error "unable to calculate image disk size".
I solved it by just installing Docker Desktop on C drive instead of using "mklink" to install it on other drives.