Docker Desktop - random WSL distro terminated abruptly
Once in a while i get a Docker Desktop - WSL distro terminated abruptly message and docker desktop stops working, this seems completely random could be once in a month situation or even three times a week. Normally docker desktop runs 24 hours per day. 

Possibley related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76922143/docker-desktop-wsl-distro-terminated-abruptly
